# Visual Studio 2013 Error ADO.NET Entity Data Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, ado.net, entity-framework-6, ado.net-entity-data-model

I am having a problem with Visual Studio 2013.
I start by creating a new project, a ASP.NET Web Application MVC. Then when i try to add a ADO.NET Entity Data Model i get this error:

[image]

I had this problem before, but i updated Windows Server, which im using, and Visual Studio too, and it stay good. But now i updated a Sql Server Tools in VS, and this error appears again.

This all happened because i am having a problem, which is, when i try to add a ADO.NET Entity Data Model the wizard closes at the middle of the process. I have searched inumerous posts here on StackOverflow but nothing resolved.
I am using .Net Framework 4.5 and Entity Framework 6

If somebody could help i would be eternally grateful

Comment: Did you try: Go into view->Server Explorer and remove any "Data Connections".

Comment: yes. i also tried go to C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\ServerExplorer and removed the file there

Comment: That is why i never update my IDE xD....you can try unistalling, cleaning the registry, and installing visual studio 2013 and Visual Studio 2013 Update 4....

Comment: now im trying to Repair the update 5. if the error continues i will remove the update then

Comment: i read that the error that im having, 0xc00005, its because the software it's trying to access memory but it's not allowed. they say that it can be because of .NET framework..

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the error is gone, i just removed the Update 5 from Visual Studio and it's fine now.

But now there is the other error, when i try to create a ADO.NET Entity Data Model, at the middle of the process, the wizard just closes and the Model it's not created.

Any suggestions?